# Java Retry Approach For a Failed Webservice Call

Tags: java, asynchronous, architecture

Need a suggestion to design a better retry solution for a failed service call.

For example: In **my application** I do have a list of items which gets passed to a service method. Which then used to persist the list bean into **other application** DB. And the service we are calling is OSB service which we don't have access to.In case due to any issue (service down), it inserts the failed bean into **my applications DB**. So I have a LOG table which is having a list of failed bean with date and error message.

Which I have to read and keep reprocessing it for a particular time period.

**My-Solution:**
1. Retrieve a list of bean from LOG table.
2. Prepare an asynchronous call using FutureTask.
3. Then try three times at regular interval.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at messaging patterns.  You are re-creating messaging patterns, but from scratch.  If you are going to do this, try looking at something a little more robust than fixed-time retries:

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-retry-pattern-with-exponential-back

Otherwise, use some middleware to accomplish this, either an ESB like MuleESB or Apache ServiceMix...  They will be much more robust, and include things like hospital queues, configurable retries, escalation, etc.

Comment: Nice, thanks, i have been looking out the same suggestion. Which will be robust. Thanks for pointing  out the tools and API